# Spring integration tests: inject @Value while using MockitoJUnitRunner

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, spring-test

The example below works correct. The problem is that I do need `@InjectMocks` annotation. And when I replace `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class` with `MockitoJUnitRunner.class` everything breaks (`bar = null` instead of `testValue`).

*How to fix?*

```
//@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) // not work (
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = FooTest.Config.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "some.bar.value=testValue",
})
public class FooTest {

    @Value("${some.bar.value}")
    String bar;

    @Test
    public void testValueSetup() {
        assertEquals("testValue", bar);
    }

    @Configuration
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertiesResolver() {
            return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mockito also provides a rule to overcome situations where it's not possible to use the `MockitoJUnitRunner`, e.g.:

```
@Rule
public MockitoRule mockito = org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnit.rule();
```

...or you could set up Mockito manually:

```
@Before 
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to this combo of ClassRule and Rule to enable the same functionality the SpringRunner does.

```
    @ClassRule
    public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

    @Rule
    public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();
```

and then use the MockitoRunner like normal.

Additionally, you could always just mock the dependencies directly with `Mockito.mock` etc. the annotations approach while slightly cleaner can lead to some annoying runtime issues if the test isn't simple, esp. in the case of `@InjectMocks`.

Curious why you need the Mockito runner within a SpringBoot project? You can use MockBeans to mock out Spring Beans when required. Smells like an XY Problem as I've never had to use the MockitoRunner.